# Get the names of classes for fine tuned model in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have fine-tuned a model in Keras 2.2.4, now I want to be able to know to which label correspond the value in the predict array:

On my training side:

```
def get_model(): 

    # create the base pre-trained model  
    base_model = VGG16(input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3),weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
 
    # Freeze the layers except the last 4 layers
    for layer in base_model.layers[:-4]:
        layer.trainable = False

    # Create the model
    model = Sequential()

    # Add the vgg convolutional base model
    model.add(base_model)
    
    # Add new layers
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(classes_num, activation='softmax'))

    return  model


# create model for finetune
model = get_model() 

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(  
      rotation_range=90,      
      horizontal_flip=True,    
      vertical_flip=True,
      zoom_range=0.4)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_path,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_path,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical')


model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=samples_per_epoch,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    callbacks=[plot_losses],
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

On predict side:

```
#Load the pre-trained models  
model = load_model(model_path) 

#model.load_weights(model_weights_path) 
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])


img = load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
preds = model.predict_classes(x)

ipdb> preds
array([3], dtype=int64)
```

I did not find a way to save the classes names in the model, the only way I have found is to use the class_indices at the training time and save them to a different file to get the label name and their index value.

Is there a way to save the classes names in the model to later use it alone ?
How to get the corresponding classes to my array ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use model.predict_classes(x) to get the class names directly. This [link](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.0.0/models/sequential/) might be useful.

Comment: Thx, I tryed the predict_classes but with no success, got array([3], dtype=int64)

Comment: Looks like your data preprocessing step has changed names into integers. Can you share your data preparation code

Comment: The code which you used to create X and Y for modelling

Comment: Ok, sorry I'm beginning, I updated with all the code.